# docker-compose exit depends_on service after tests

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, docker, docker-compose

How do I get a service container to exit once the dependent container has finished?

I have test suite running in the app_unittestbot container that depends_on a postgresql db server (postgres:9.5-alpine) running in separate container. Once the test suite exits, I want to check the return code of the test suite and halt the database container. With the docker-compose.yml below, the db service container never halts.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  app_postgresql95:
    build: ./postgresql95/
    ports:
     - 54321:5432

  app_unittestbot:
    command: /root/wait-for-it.sh app_postgresql95:5432 --timeout=60 -- nose2 tests
    build: ./unittestbot/
    links:
      - app_postgresql95
    volumes:
      - /app/src:/src
    depends_on:
      - 'app_postgresql95'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` to have compose stop all the containers if any one of them exits. That will likely solve your use case.

For something a little more resilient, I'd probably split this into two compose files so that an abort on postgresql doesn't get accidentally registered as a successful test. Then you'd just run those files in the order you need:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml      up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml      down
```